# Issue with React, Typescript & Webpack adding bundle.js to page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When I build my project, it builds fine, and creates the bundle.js file, however when navigating to the page at http://localhost:8080/ I'm presented with the warning in the console:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js”.`

I'm really confused by this, as it appears that everything is building and starting correctly.

I've gone through each of these pages: [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter) [2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) [3](https://hackernoon.com/react-with-typescript-and-webpack-654f93f34db6) [4](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) and tried what they show on there, however nothing changes.

My webpack.config.js file:

```
"use strict"

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './App.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/",
        contentBase: "./public",
        hot: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }]
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "App.tsx"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "App.tsx",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.6.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

App.tsx is as simple as this, just until I can get this to work with this test:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./App.css";

export interface Props {}
export interface State {}

class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
       <div className="test">
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And for reference in case I'm missing something really simple, my file structure looks like this:

```
  project
  |- package.json
  |- package-lock.json
  |- tsconfig.json
  |- tslint.json
  |- webpack.config.js
  |- App.tsx
  |- App.css
  |- /dist
    |- bundle.js
  |- /public
    |- index.html
  |- /node_modules
```

Before switching this to Typescript with React (i was only using React with webpack and then decided to use typescript, react and webpack), it was adding the div to the root div without issue, and I'm hoping to get it to do the same thing, however right now it just loads the `index.html` page with only the `<div id="root"></div>` and `<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: If you are using the cli starter why do you have a custom webpack config?Have you ejected the project inorder to use the custom config. If so you need to add a some stuff for webpack to convert the ts to js

https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: @varoons I have not ejected. I am using a custom webpack config because every guide that I have found shows that you need to create one, and mentions that you have to include webpack-cli for version 4+. The link that you included in your comment is one of the links that I included in the post that I have already looked at, and my code already includes everything on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out it was just a simple problem. I guess index.html needs to be in the same directory as bundle.js. Once I moved index.html into dist it worked without issue.